Pandas HTML generation, reproducible output
I am writing a Pandas dataframe as HTML using this code
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ "a": [1] })
print(df.style.to_html())

I ran it once and it produced this output
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<table id="T_f9297">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_f9297_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >a</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_f9297_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
      <td id="T_f9297_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

But when I run the same program again a moment later it gives
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<table id="T_d628d">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_d628d_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >a</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_d628d_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
      <td id="T_d628d_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

I would like to get the same output each time.  That is, the T_f9297 and T_d628d identifiers shouldn't change from one run to the next.  How can I get that?
I believe that I could generate HTML without any CSS styling and without the identifiers, but I do want CSS (I just omitted it from my example) and I'm happy to have the identifiers, as long as I get the same output given the same input data.
I am using Python 3.11.7 and Pandas 2.1.4.

pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_html has a table_uuid parameter:

table_uuid str, optional: Id attribute assigned to the <table> HTML element in the format: <table id="T_<table_uuid>" ..>

If not provided it generates a random uuid. If set it will use the uuid provided:
print(df.style.to_html(table_uuid="my_table_id"))

Output:
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<table id="T_my_table_id">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0" >&nbsp;</th>
      <th id="T_my_table_id_level0_col0" class="col_heading level0 col0" >a</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="T_my_table_id_level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
      <td id="T_my_table_id_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


Thanks.  I found I could also say print(df.style.set_uuid('abcde').to_html())

"Styler’s initially assigned value" could you explain a little more on that?  Perhaps I can set this initially assigned value at the start of my program and get deterministic HTML generation for every call?

@EdAvis that was a quote from the docs but I didn't really understand it either so I've looked at the source and edited my answer so it's clearer. Basically if you provide a uuid it uses it, otherwise it generates a random hex string of length of 5. If you want to set a value at the start of the program, you'll need to pass that as an argument to the table_uuid parameter.

Got it, thanks.  What I'd really like is to set the random seed used by Pandas for generating these ids.  I could do that once at the start of my program and not need to modify every to_html call.

@EdAvis I don't think you could do that as it's not pandas which generates the uuid - it's the uuid library.
